# Loading vuetify in a package that i use in a vuetify project

Tags: npm, vuejs2, vuetify.js

What is the correct way of loading vuetify into a package that i use in a vuetify project?
When serving projects it all seems to work fine but when i build the project i've got some issues with the css/sass

things i've tried:

- With vuetify loader: the css is loaded twice so i can't overwrite sass variables
- Without vuetify loader: the package doesn't have the vuetify css, so it looks horrible
- Without vuetify loader with vuetify.min.css:  the css is loaded twice so i can't overwrite sass variables, and the loaded css is all the css so it's huge

My package is called vuetify-resource, and this is the source code of the `index.js` (without the vuetify loader) At this point everything works on `npm run serve` But when i build the package doesn't have "access" to the vuetify css.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import VuetifyResourceComponent from './VuetifyResource.vue';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
const VuetifyResource = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.component('vuetify-resource', VuetifyResourceComponent);

    },
};

export default VuetifyResource;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve my issue i had to do a couple of things.**

1. Make peer dependencies of vuetify and vue
2. add vuetify to the webpack externals, so when someone uses the package, the package uses that projects vuetify
3. not longer import vue and vuetify in the index.js it's not needed, the project that uses the package imports that
4. import the specific components that you use in every .vue file

---

**for example:**

Vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        externals: {'vuetify/lib': 'vuetify/lib'},
    },
};
```

index.js

```
import VuetifyResourceComponent from './VuetifyResource.vue';

const VuetifyResource = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.component('vuetify-resource', VuetifyResourceComponent);

    },
};

export default VuetifyResource;
```

part of the component.vue

```
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
    name: 'vuetify-resource',
    components: {
        VDataTable
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 in Ricardo's answer is not needed if you use `vuetify-loader`, it will do the job for you.

And I would modify step 2 to also exclude Vuetify's styles/css from your bundle. If you don't exclude them you can run into styling issues when the Vuetify version differ between your library and your application.

Use a regular expression in vue.config.js like this: `configureWebpack: { externals: /^vuetify\// }`. That way, only your own styles are included in the library bundle.

Comment: This used to be the way i did this as wel, until i found out this way my css was loaded twice in the project that uses this package. Becuase it's imported twice one of them don't contain the variables.scss changes and therefor you could n't change variables.

Are you saying you don't have this isue this way? Do you know if this is a recent behaviour?

someone of the vuetify core team helped me with my anwser